# bootstrap alert dismiss on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I've tried all the code I could find on here and google and nothing seems to work. I'm trying to have my alerts dismissed on mouse click anywhere on the page. 
I have `//=require bootstrap` in my application.js and it is last in the list. The following code is what I would like to be dismissible.

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  <div class="alert alertPrimary alert-dismissible fade in textCenter">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"></button>
   <% if value.is_a?(String) %>
     <%= value %>
   <% else %>
   <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

and

```
return '' if resource.errors.empty?

messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
html = <<-HTML
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in textCenter">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"></button>
  #{messages}
</div>
HTML

html.html_safe
```

I can't seem to find any javascript/jquery that does the trick. When I add an 'x' in the button code it closes the alert when you click that but that's not the behaviour I'm looking for. I just want the alert gone when the user clicks anywhere.

my entire `application.js` file

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
// Use JQuery selector and bind a function to the click event
// $("body") selects the <body> tag
$("body").click(function(){  
    $(".alert").alert("close");
});
```

This method is available through [bootstrap's alert plugin](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_alert.asp) that is part of `bootstrap.js`

## Example to play with:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").click(function() {
    $(".alert").alert("close");
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="content">
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included the bootstrap.js file? https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js I'm not sure if bootstrap loads JQuery, if not you should add it too

Comment: You should also set the correct selector instead of `.body` if you haven't done that

Comment: updated my post with my entire `application.js` file. why is `.body` the wrong selector? isn't that what i would require? I interpret the above code to say "once the page has finished loading listen for clicks and if there is one on html body then close all alert classes"

Comment: No in my example I used a class `.body` but now I notice it's probably confusing, I will change that right away

Comment: sorry, I should've caught that. i'm just learning. i know the `.` means class and `#` means id. my bad.

Comment: got it now. with the following. had to restart my server which was weird. `$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").click(function() {
    $(".alert").alert("close");
  });
});`